# I am getting error while update-database command to make tables related to Identity. column parameter or variable:cannot find data type datetimeoffset

Tags: c#, database, model-view-controller, migration, datetimeoffset

I try to update the database to make tables related to Identity, and I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity, autogenerated public class IdentityUser, when I write the command, I recieve this error:
**Column, parameter, or variable #14: Cannot find data type datetimeoffset.**

I'm using MVC .net 5 and SQL Management Studio 19

Comment: please show your code with text

Comment: from the migration file:
' LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "datetimeoffset", nullable: true),'
here is the problem

Comment: Data Type DateTimeOffset is not supported.
You must use datetime,LockoutEnd = table.Column<datetime>(type: "datetime", nullable: true),

Answer (score 0):

You can just use datetime instead of datetimeoffset.